# 'Back' browser action in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, browser

Can the 'Back' browser functionality be invoked from a Rails 'Back' link?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In Rails 3 and earlier:

```
link_to_function "Back", "history.back()"
```

In Rails 4, this method has been removed. See Andreas's comment.

Comment: Be aware that link_to_function is depreciated in Rails 4.1. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324919/status-of-rails-link-to-function-deprecation

Comment: enjoy a `undefined method 'link_to_function' for #<#<Class` if you still give this a try in Rails 4.1+

Comment: I'm using Rails 4.2.5.1 at the moment. I found that I needed to send the Javascript in the options hash, as `onclick: 'history.back()`, rather than in the URL parameter (which didn't work, at least when I tried it with Firefox).

Answer (score 216):

Use

```
<%= link_to 'Back', :back %>
```

This is specificied in the RDoc [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#M001565)

This generates some Javascript to navigate backward.  I've just tested it, and it works.

Comment: It doesn't work 'exactly' like a Back button. All the inputted form data is cleared.

Comment: Yeah, I feel like this only really gets most people half way there. If you truly want emulate the back button, then you also want all the previous params intact.

Comment: This will not use `javascript:history.back()` when `request.referer` is present.

Comment: If you have this back button on two pages it will cause the user to just go back and forth between those two pages. It doesn't actually traverse through the history.

Comment: This can create a nightmare of a user experience in the case of failed form submissions and cases of similar nature that screw up where the user expects the back button to bring them.

Answer (score 22):

This is working in Rails 5.1 along with Turbolinks.

```
link_to 'Back', 'javascript:history.back()'
```

Answer (score 13):

In Rails 4.2, I got it to work with this:

```
<a href="javascript:history.back()">Refine Search</a>
```

I stole this off of [@cpm’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/620985/), except that `link_to("Refine Search", :back)` didn’t do the job I wanted while pasting in the generated code `<a href="javascript:history.back()">Refine Search</a>` did it perfectly.

Comment: Yes, `link_to("Refine Search", :back)` will just save the last action w/o any params and put you back there where as your solution uses js

Comment: @ohhh it doesn't work for me either: undefined method `stringify_keys' for :back:Symbol

Comment: @facundofarias, that sounds unrelated, what is the exact syntax of your `link_to`?

Comment: @ohhh it was: link_to("Test", :back)

Comment: @facundofarias, and you def. weren't passing it a block?

Answer (score 11):

You can use `link_to("Hello", :back)` to generate `<a href="javascript:history.back()">Hello</a>`.

Comment: [In most cases, it will use the referrer to go back. If there is no referrer, then it will do `javascript:history.back()`.](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.1.4/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb#L33-L58). Checked the code from Rails 3.0 - 6.1.

Answer (score 3):

This will work similarly as browser back button try this

`<%= link_to 'Back', 'javascript:history.go(-1);' %>`

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1152759/rthbound) from the user [rthbound](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1152759/rthbound)! As he notes, `link_to` with the symbol `:back` does not always generate a “real” back event as if the user clicked on their browser’s Back button. It can also be a resubmit of the action that loaded the current view.

The [documentation for Rails 4.2.6](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) says this about `link_to` and the `:back` symbol:

> Using a `:back` Symbol instead of an options hash will generate a link to the 
>   referrer (a JavaScript back link will be used in place of a referrer if none
>   exists).

Answer (score 0):

##### Rails <= 4.0

Using

```rb
link_to_function "Back", "history.back()"
```

seems to be exactly like hitting the back button in the browser. All inputted form data is still there when you get back.

Answer (score 0):

If you like me do not want the behaviour of `link_to "cancel", :back` you could implement a helper method which either links to the records index path or show path. (i.e `teams_path` or `team_path(@team)`

```
module CancelFormButtonHelper
  def cancel_button(record)
    index_path = record.class.to_s.pluralize.downcase + "_path"
    path = record.persisted? ? record : eval(index_path)

    link_to "Cancel", path
  end
end
```

which can then be used as `<%= cancel_button @team %>` within a form for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use js function window.history.back()

```
 = link_to 'Back', onclick: "window.history.back();"
```