# In ruby, how do you mess with the back button? Redirect user somewhere if they click back button?

Tags: ruby, erb, back

In otherform.erb I have

```
<%= link_to "Back", redirect "/" %>
```

But then I can't even view the front page when I start my server, even without pressing anything. It gives me syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' ...k_to "Back", do erb :index end ).to_s); @_out_buf.concat "... ... ^

So what's the proper way to control the back button in ruby, in the erb documents?

Comment: Are you talking about the Black button on the browser?. You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620962/back-browser-action-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that was for rails. Is there a way without using rails? I am just using ruby.

Comment: just do `link_to "Back", "/"`

Comment: Hmm, now it says no method link_to for #

Comment: If you are not using `rails` (or atleast `actionview`) then you cannot use `link_to` as this an `ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper` method. you could just build the standard html `<a href="/"><button>Back</button></a>` no need for erb

Comment: I would like to be able to control the browser's back button instead of making a back button.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
redirect_to :back
# is a shorthand for:
redirect_to request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]
```

Going back to root it's a "homepage" link, not a "back" link.

Comment: I want to redirect the user to the homepage, anytime when they click the back button.

Comment: So add `root :controller => 'static', :action => '/' ` to your routes and then you can use `redirect_to root_path` where you need.

Assuming that you have a public/index.html, that will work!

Comment: I am not using rails. Is there a way to do it without rails?